# Getting pretty urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the users to get redirected to **'website.com/user-profile.php?user_username=abc'** when any user visits **'website.com/abc'**.

However, I want to achieve this **without breaking the CSS, JS and other images** that might be in the pages.

I had tried the following code but it **breaks the CSS, JS and all the images**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)?$ user-profile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Any help about how can I achieve the above mentioned without breaking the images, JS and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put a .htacces like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z]+)?$ user-profile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's redirecting the right page but the CSS, JS and the Images are broken.

Comment: Again, the same thing is happening. The images, JS and CSS are broken but when I visit the page website.com/user-profile.php?user_username=abc, everything works fine.

Comment: Check the url to the css and js resources, if these are relative change it to absolute (starts with "/") because website.com/abc have diferent path that website.com/profile/abc.

Comment: Worked after making the changes according to above comment! Thanks @Juan M

Answer (score 0):

Your css, js, and image links are probably all broken because they are relative URLs, and your URL base changed when the browser's location bar changed from:

```
http://website.com/(something)
```

to:

```
http://website.com/profile/(something)
```

So you need to either change all your links to be absolute URL's (that start with `/`) or add a URL base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```